Seeking Book and Online Resource Recommendations for Problem-Solving
I'm looking for recommendations for books or online resources that emphasize problem-solving. While I don't mind if relevant theory is introduced along the way, I'm not looking for materials that focus too heavily on lengthy, rigorous proofs.
I will soon be graduating from high school, and I have a solid understanding of basic concepts in elementary calculus, elementary  probability and statistics, elementary number theory, and some understanding of linear algebra, and i have done some high school contest problems before.
Which resources would you recommend? If possible, please specify the difficulty level of the material so I can find something that matches my skill level.
Many thanks in advance for your help!

When I was graduating from high school  in 1955 the book that spoke to me about how mathematics works was George Polya's Induction and Analogy in Mathematics (Volume I of his two volume set on Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning).
It's not dated even though you know more mathematics than I knew when I first read it.
Earlier the book that turned me on to mathematics was Hugo Steinhaus' Mathematical Snapshots.

I suggest this book: How Not to Be Wrong: The Power of Mathematical Thinking by Jordan Ellenberg. It is relevant to problem-solving and it gives examples, it is about how maths knowledge are applied into real life situation and how we can correctly apply them.
This link
https://books.google.com/books/about/How_Not_to_be_Wrong.html?id=_EQCDAAAQBAJ
or
https://newrevenue.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/how-not-to-be-wrong-ellenberg-20169131536812.pdf
